# Version Control Scenario

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I am relying on Github/Bitbucket/Version control Gurus.

The scenario is that I have a DEV server and a LIVE server. I've made a repository so that I can keep version control centralized. In the image below (forget use cases for a moment..), I have made two copies of the LIVE and DEV server to my repository so I could practically make a brach from the master, where the master is the LIVE server and the branch would be the dev server. Therefore any changes I am happy with in the DEV server, i would then merge into the master(LIVE server). This is what I am thinking. What would you suggest in this case?

[image: Representation of my repository]

Comment: Not sure what you mean, "What would you suggest?" You have a process, so use it.

Comment: @meagar I just wanted to know if you had any better ideas than mine. Perhaps there could be a better process than mine. That's all I wanted to know. But I'm definitely going to apply this as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have a confusion between folders vs branches, repos vs servers and basic workflow. There's no local repo vs remote repo. **The scenario you describe has just one repo**. You can have a local working copy in your localhost, a clone in your production server and of course a remote in github or wherever you want. But working copies are still **mirrors of the same repo**.

I believe the simplest layout that would offer the same purpose that yours is

- **Dev Server** (for this example, it'll be your localhost)

  - Holds **one** working copy of your project. For example in `/home/user/project`
  - You keep this working copy in the `develop` branch except when merging.
  - You commit and then push to your origin remote, which is  `git://github.com/Arty/project.git`
- **Web Server**

  - It runs a webserver (apache, nginx, etc)
  - Webserver has two vhosts
  - Vhost1 has server_name `dev.project.com` and document root is `/var/www/dev_project`
  - Vhost2 has server_name `www.project.com` and document root is `/var/www/project`
  - Both document roots are working copies of `git://github.com/Arty/project.git`, but the first one is standing in the `develop` branch, while the second one is standing at the `master` branch.
- **Github Remote a.k.a. Origin**

  - This one needs no explanation

The workflow to add new features would be

1. You stand in /home/user/project  (`cd /home/user/project`)
2. You are in the `develop`branch (`git checkout develop`)
3. You hack your changes and then commit them (`git commit -a -m "my new feature"`)
4. You push to origin  (`git push origin develop`)
5. You log into your web server (`ssh dev.project.com`)
6. You stand at /var/www/dev_project (`cd /var/www/dev_project`)
7. You pull recent changes from origin (`git pull origin develop`)
8. You logout from your web server and stand back at `/home/user/project` on local
9. You verify that your changes are working as
   expected at `dev.project.com`
10. If they don't, repeat stages 3 to 8
11. If they are, you switch to master branch (`git checkout master`)
12. You merge from develop  (`git merge develop`)
13. You resolve conflicts if there are any, and push to origin (`git push origin master`)
14. You log into your web server again
15. You stand at /var/www/project (`cd /var/www/project`)
16. You pull from origin (`git pull origin master`)
17. You verify that your production  website www.project.com is running as intented
18. You're done until you want to start another feature.

There are much more elaborated schemes, but as long as you don't understand the internal workings of Git they will only confuse you more.

For the branching scheme, I've been using [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for the last two years in a team of 8 developers, and it works flawlessly. Again, if you're working alone and these are your first steps with Git, you might want to wait before embracing gitflow.

Comment: You're right! What I should have said is "Cloned Repo"(localhost) and "Origin Repo" as opposed to what I had on my diagram. But thanks for the answer I Will take this in consideration. Cheers